# Generic S3 bucket policy for cross-account access for muliple acounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

i want to allow a bunch of AWS acccounts write permissions into one single S3 bucket.
All accounts are organized and allocated in different AWS organizations. Therefore i want to limit access based on their org-id.

Additionally, I want to restrict access to the object level and allow access to a prefix, which should be specified by the source AWS AccountId.

**I don't want** to allow each account like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/111111111111",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/111111111111/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/222222222222",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/222222222222/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am looking for is a generic policy by using the source AccountId as variable. Something like this:

```json
{
    "Version" : "2012-10-17", 
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:SourceAccountId}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:SourceAccountId}/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": [
                        "o-XXXXX",
                        "o-YYYYY",
                        "o-ZZZZZ"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately the variable `${aws:SourceAccountId}` is not available and only an imaginary placeholder for something i am looking for. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does it have to be bucket policy? Why not create a role which other accounts could assume to access to your bucket?

Comment: This is plan B. I want to avoid that. Because there are dozens of accounts and a ton of roles to adjust. I want to reduce the management overhead and want to restrict access at the highest level available.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you **can't** introduce new variables to IAM policy language. The IAM policies also don't have any looping mechanisms to generate such policies dynamically based on provided list of account id numbers.

Therefore, for such scenarios, usually people look into programmatic solutions. Most notably to **Infrastructure as Code** (IaC) tools, which would allow **creation and management** of such policies through code. For IaC at AWS two popular choices are AWS CloudFormation (CFN) and Terraform (TF).

In your case TF could be better as it has reach and well develop support for loops and dynamic creation of resources, including IAM policies and its content.

The other choices would be programmatic solutions involving regular programming languages (Python, Bash) and **AWS SDK and CLI**, or using IAM role as I indicated in the comments.